# Drop down buttons on website stopped working

Tags: html, css

When clicking the drop down menu nothing is happening, not sure what changed as it was working a short while ago. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" style="width: 169%;" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span id="dropdown_button">10 Closest Amenities</span> <span class="caret" style="margin-top: 9px;float: right;"></span> </button>
```

An example of where this can be seen is [here.](https://www.trustedlivingcare.com/item/bozeman-lodge/)

This one stopped working as well.

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Search by cities in Montana <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span> <span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span> </button>
```

assuming caused by the same action.

Seen [here](https://www.trustedlivingcare.com/loc/Montana/)

Thank you everyone!

Comment: This looks like bootstrap. Bootstrap is shipping with some js and this is probably responsible for toggling that dropdown. Are you sure all required bootstrap files are imported? Maybe someone delete a file or folder?

Answer (score 0):

From what I noticed an event is missing from your h3 tag to change the display of this class that has display "none".

```
.header-one .nav-menu-container.nav-menu-main, .header-two .nav-menu-container.nav-menu-main {
    display: none;
}
```

Can any of your javascript not be loading?